# typescript type mismatch issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was going through [react typescript cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/) and one code snippet caught my attention:

```
export function createCtx<A>(defaultValue: A) {
 type UpdateType = Dispatch<SetStateAction<typeof defaultValue>>;
 const defaultUpdate: UpdateType = () => defaultValue;
 const ctx = createContext({
   state: defaultValue,
   update: defaultUpdate,
 });

 function Provider(props: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
   const [state, update] = useState(defaultValue);
   return <ctx.Provider value={{ state, update }} {...props} />;
 }
 return [ctx, Provider] as const; // alternatively, [typeof ctx, typeof Provider]
}
```

the purpose of this function function is to create a context and provider based on the `defaultValue` passed to the function.
I have difficulty understanding the first two lines of the function:

```
 type UpdateType = Dispatch<SetStateAction<typeof defaultValue>>;
 const defaultUpdate: UpdateType = () => defaultValue;
```

`Dispatch` is defined as:

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

and `SetStateAction` as:

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

this make `() => defaultValue` not assignable to type `UpdateType`, How this can possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I let you check this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeARYAZzBRjQAtsBlJGKmUpAQQ2AgDts0pUYkBhDnwAeWOAAUoEMIQDqwGOX7lgAGwAmPTnACuhJPUYBfOADMpIOAHIe6GFYDcAWABQrpMMiwzO9qw5w3LwCMMIAPEwAfAAU6kimKDqqMABqKKo6SABccEwAlLiucDAAnmBIcACqYOqMACplFQC8cATEpBRhNHQMfCwwbOxhpeUQpnBxCUmp6ZmRkc4ugRyE8JOJydW1fDlb9Y1wLdEFTZET8RszGUiLy+yrgaGHgbZ8guwiMNE4RXBwq4wcutpmlrphfroaoDzlNNlC+OClkY8osiqZfP52BIpAA3YBxKDRMBSGQ5STSOQKJQqDRaMI4IyRAo-JZ-NAreAAbQBCMh2yQAF1nnoDL0kLELiDZkgURCeDAdFAsWEMMIAHTkvEEuA46VNHA4f5i7A6eEVIwmHBq63EikmAD0CyKRiK8sVWM5quwmvxSCgQpQhDuqwccHt9rg6T4StIwBxSFUJWwnJGSDGj2E2FT6Z9BIFriMQA) to see that there is no problem.

To elaborate, let's unroll the `UpdateType`:

```js
type DVT = typeof defaultValue;
type UpdateType = (value: DVT | ((prevState: DVT) => DVT) => void;
```

And the function `() => defaultValue;` has a type:

```js
type FunType = () => DVT;
```

So first let's consider the return value: `void` should not accept a return value right? Well not exactly, `void` does not force a function to not return a value. It's very common to assign a function that return a value to a type with a `void` return type.

See [Assignability of Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#assignability-of-functions) for this and this of course [Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).

Then the argument value, the function `() => defaultValue` ignore the arguments so it's safe to use it an `UpdateType` type. You could have written `(value) => defaultValue`, but `value` would be unused, so TypeScript consider it safe (which is).

See [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).

Comment: Very nice, I thought typescript is stricter than that but it turns out that I am wrong.